# How to add Shared via [my app] when sharing content from an Android app to popular social networks?

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, sharing

My Android application allows users to read full articles from various blogs and share the posts using Android's in-built sent action:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

When I share an article, Twitter indicates it is shared via Twitter for Android, and Facebook simply has an RSS icon with no "shared via" at all.

What is the procedure of getting my app's title to appear next to "Shared via" for those social networks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Twitter you'd need to do the sharing directly through your own application, the API key you use to share with is associated with the 'shared via' link. If you share through another twitter application like Twitter's official app or TweetDeck then the 'share via' link will be to their app as the article was shared using their api key. There are libraries and tutorial on how to implement twitter api yourself.

Answer (score 1):

@ernes7a this is an old question so don't know if still relevant.  Socialize handles the "shared via" text.  You can check it out at http://www.GetSocialize.com & full feature list at http://go.GetSocialize.com/features

DROdio

Comment: Thanks for the link, Daniel. The solution sure looks interesting.

Comment: Sure thing, let me know how it goes.  I'd like to hear your rants or raves. - DROdio

Answer (score 0):

To get your name into the networks, i doubt that you can use the built-in sharing feature. In both cases (facebook or android) the application actually submitting the content (post or tweet) to the network gets the icon / mention. In case of using the built-in method, that will always be the twitter for android or the Facebook android app. You'd have to implement the sharing yourself. Have a look at pulse or other apps, that use these kinds of features.