# Sharing text via Facebook app, How to change "shared via Facebook for Android"?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, share

When I share text on Facebook via Intent --> Facebook app it appears on FB with "Shared via Facebook for Android". Im wondering if I can change it to "Shared via AppName for Android". ?
Have a great day everyone ! :)

Comment: I guess Ive found an answer here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337475/how-to-add-shared-via-my-app-when-sharing-content-from-an-android-app-to-popula

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can...

1. Create an application on facebook
2. Downlaod the facebook sdk for android
3. Add to your class

> Facebook facebook = new Facebook("your_add_id");

1. Add this code to publish

   ```
   facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "read_stream" }, new DialogListener() {
       public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

       public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

       public void onError(DialogError e) {}

       public void onCancel() {}
   });

   Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
   parameters.putString("message", "Test Photo");
   parameters.putString("attachment", "{\"name\":\"My Test Image\"," +"\"href\":\""+"http://www.google.com"+"\"," +"\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\""+"http://www.google.com/logos/mucha10-hp.jpg"+"\",\"href\":\""+"http://www.google.com"+"\"}]" +"}");
   facebook.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters, null);
   ```

this is the code to publish a link or image I forgot .. anyway this is just an idea